# Test $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}$ for convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Applying the ratio test to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}$ with $x_n=\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}$ we get

\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\bigg|&=\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{(n+1)^2}}}{\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}}\\&=\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{(n+1)^2}}\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}\\&=\frac{(n+1)n!\cdot2^{n^2}}{n!\cdot2^{n^2}\cdot2^{2n+1}}\\&=\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}
\end{align*}
Quick question now: Is it sufficient here to state that $2^{2n+1}$ obviously grows faster than $n+1$ (and therefore our term converges towards $0$ and our series passed the test) or do I need to generally prove this first (e.g. by induction)?

Comment: Depends on your instructor. It is an easy application of l'Hopital's rule though.

Comment: You can not use Lopital rule on sequence  only for functions

Comment: You can prove that $n+1<2^{n+1}$, and thus $\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}<\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @LinkingPark True, but if you consider the function $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2^{2x+1}}$, then you can use L'Hopital's rule on that and make conclusions about the sequence itself.

Comment: It is sufficient to *prove* that the ratio tends to $0$. If you have lemmas about speed of convergence, you can use them. But in this case, induction is not much more "costly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$r_n:=\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}.$$

Then

$$\frac{r_n}{r_{n-1}}=\frac{n+1}{4n}\le\frac12$$ and the ratio decreases exponentially to zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$
0\le\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}} \le \frac{n^n}{2^{n^2}}
$$
by the root test for $n>1$:
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{2^{n^2}}}=\frac{n}{2^n}\le \frac{1}{2}
$$
hence the series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{n^2}}$$
converges and by comparison
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}$$
converges